# Flash[:notice] multi-lines and single line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, notice, flash-message

i want to pass to `flash[:notice]` an Array of string and a single String
(in two different times)

example:

```
multi_lines << "Product: #{product.title} disponibile in #{product_quantity}<br/>"
multi_lines << "Product: #{product.title} disponibile in #{product_quantity}<br/>"
notice: multi_lines
```

And

```
single_text = "Hello"
notice: single_text
```

I have in my view the following code:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id= "notice"><%= notice.join("<br/>").html_safe %></p>
<% end %>
```

Of corse , when i pass the single string Rails say me that the join method doesn't exist in the String class.
How can overpass the error?

Thanky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work.

```
single_text = ["Hello"]
notice: single_text
```

or perhaps simpler

```
single_text = "Hello"
notice: Array.new(1, single_text)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. I tried to create a sort of if-statement in the view , that check the class of the object and executes a specific flash work. but it return me the same error. "the string doesn t have the join method"

Comment: You may be overcomplicating things. flash expects an array of strings. I'll add that .html_safe should only be used at the point the string is created to be certain that string is indeed html safe. I suspect also that you are overwriting notice rather than adding to it.

Comment: i write :  notice: "Hello world" in one case

Comment: Yes that will cause notice to become a string. Make it an array and add it to notice.

Comment: ok . Is it possible to change the logic of the view flash :notice , instead to edit the string into an array?

Comment: Possibly, but that seems overkill. Why not turn the string into an array as you pass it to notice?

Comment: it's ok , i ll do as you said. ;)  i was just asking thank you man